# Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit non MS synchronization

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlite, synchronization

I am thinking about using the MS Sync Framework Toolkit to sync mobile database subsets of data to the cloud.  I will be using Android and iOS, and I only need to sync their individual local copies of the SQLite DB to the cloud.

How well does MS Sync Framework handle filtering and data subsets, and how well does it run on non-windows based platforms, mainly Java/Android and iOS?  The mobile environments use SQLLite and the cloud is Microsoft based.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

the Sync Framework Toolkit has an iPhone sample that you can take a look at. you may have to build your own provider for SQLLite though.

You should be able to filter data as well when provisioning the scopes (scopes are group of tables that are synched together in a sync session).